# get password from password field

Tags: java, jpasswordfield, getpasswd

I have put a Password Field on my frame.  I have named it pwText(Variable name).  I am unable to get the input from the Password Field so that I can do a comparison.

Please note that the password that need to be entered is "userjim".

Comment: What did you try? Consider posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

```
String password = new String(pwText.getPassword());
if (password.equals("userjim") {
    // correct
} else {
    // not correct
}
```